# Trying to envoke a variable in Powershell using QAD and getting a null exception

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm just trying to create a small script that pulls a CSV, then invokes Quest AD to change the password flag from password never expires and then changes it to not have to change the password at next login, in hopes of getting it to fall into the default domain policy. I've gotten it to work individually, but when I try to add a ForEach variable, I cant seem to get it to work. Here's my script. It can poll each entry in the CSV but then it nulls when I try to do anything with the $entry variable in QAD. I'm not the best at powershell so I turn to you gurus.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Add-PSSnapin Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement

$list = Import-csv “password.csv”
ForEach($entry in $list)
{
Set-QADUser $entry -UserMustChangePassword $True
Start-Sleep -Sec 1
Set-QADUser $entry -UserMustChangePassword $False
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$entry` will contain an object with properties based on the header of your csv file.

```
Import-csv “password.csv”
```

Simply typing the above will show the object. Even if you only have one column you need to call its property.

In you `ForEach` loop you would need to call `$entry.Username`. The answer is in your csv file. If your file only contains one column then you could do something like this:

```
$list = Get-Content | Select-Object -Skip 1
```

`Skip 1` would ignore a csv header. Or you could do something like this:

```
$list = Import-csv “password.csv” | Select-Object -ExpandProperty UserName
```

All of this is assumption. The content of your CSV “password.csv” contains the answer.

Comment: Matt - Thank you. I think that may be my issue. The CSV only just had the list of usernames and didn't have a header to define what the usernames are. Such a small detail. I'll give that a shot and give you credit for the answer if it work.